# Spring: Set default HttpMessageConverter format

Tags: java, spring

I have a Java/Spring application. My endpoint

```
www.url.xx/serach?q=omestuff
```

gives out JSON by default. Now I want some Endpoints for exportation.

I created a MessageConverter  for CSV:

```
public class SearchResultCsvConverter extends AbstractHttpMessageConverter {
    public SearchResultCsvConverter() {
        super(new MediaType("text", "csv"));
    }
```

and magically the endpoint

```
    www.url.xx/serach.csv?q=omestuff
```

gives out csv. Neato.

Next I wanted to make HTML-export and made HTML endpoint likewise

```
public class SearchResultHtmlConverter extends AbstractHttpMessageConverter {
    public SearchResultHtmlConverter() {
        super(new MediaType("text", "html"));
    }
```

But alas! Now the default endpoint (without file-extension) takes to this one and not the default JSON output (which would mean: no HttpMessageConverter at all in my case).

How can I set up to use no converter by default and the HTML-converter only if explicitly asked for?

-- Edit 1
The serach-endpoint looks like this

```
@RequestMapping(value="/search", method=RequestMethod.GET) 
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<?> handleSearchRequest(@RequestParam("q") final String queryString) {
```

...

I had `//produces={APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE})` in the @RequestMapping but removed it,  because CSV export does not work then..

-- Edit 2

A allready had

```
@Override
public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);
}
```

Comment: I allready have "    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);
    }"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out, I had to set

```
configurer.ignoreAcceptHeader(true)
```